# Convert single UDT object to list of UDT in Cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-types

I have two userdefined type in Cassandra. First one is using the second object as frozen object inside it.

```
CREATE TYPE my_keyspace.test (
    testid text,
    testdate text,
    testdata frozen<testdata>
);



CREATE TYPE my_keyspace.testdata (
    subject text,
    metadata text

);
```

Now my requirement is to convert this single object to list of UDT . Something like this

```
CREATE TYPE my_keyspace.test (
    testid text,
    testdate text,
    testdata list<frozen<testdata>>
);
```

Is it  possible to update single object to list of object in Cassandra. Whata are options available to update the schema.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it, is to add another field with required type using the `ALTER TYPE`, and start to use this new field, migrating existing data using some code.  Cassandra doesn't allow to change type of the existing fields, and you can't also drop a field from UDT. So your type should be something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE my_keyspace.test (
    testid text,
    testdate text,
    testdata frozen<testdata>
    testdata_lst list<frozen<testdata>>
);
```

Existing data could be migrated into a list, and then set to `null` to free the space.